# How to read a CSV file into a int[] C#

Tags: c#, string, file, matrix, int

I have a file, a.csv, which contains a square matrix of n by n dimensions, in the following format:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

And I want to read it into an int[], something like:

```
StreamReader csv = new StreamReader("a.csv");
        int n = 3
        string[] lines = new string[n];
        int[] intlines = new int[n]
        int q = 0;
        bool exiting = false;
        do
        {
            if (csv.ReadLine() != "")
            {
                exiting = true;
            }

            if (exiting == false)
            {
                lines[q] = (((csv.ReadLine()).Split(",")).ToString());
                q++;
            }
        }
        while (exiting == false);           
        Console.WriteLine("Finished Reading!");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        int q2 = 0;         
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("lines: {0}", s);
            intlines[q2] = int.Parse(s);
        }
        foreach (int i in intlines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("intlines: {0}", i.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

At the moment, there is something wrong with it as the compiler is going on about char[]'s. Anyways, how would I read the horizontal lines and the vertical lines as well, into a 2 dimensional int[]?
Thank you.

Comment: any reason you're using an array over a list?

Comment: woah nelly.  So much of what you're doing is already available in numerous libraries.  This could be done in 3-4 lines of code

Comment: @malik Ultimately, I would like to have a 2 dimensional int[] to manipulate, thus I would prefer not using lists. I have come up with: List<string[]> lines = new List<string[]>();
   int Row = 0;
   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
       string[] Line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
       lines.Add(Line);
       Row++;
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("a.csv"))
{
    var myArray = sr.ReadToEnd()
        .Split('\n')
        .SelectMany(s => s.Split(',')
            .Select(x => int.Parse(x)))
        .ToArray<int>();

    foreach(var x in myArray)
        Console.WriteLine (x);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely something like this or `File.ReadAllLines`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using CSVhelper by Josh Close on nuget and github https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

it's an excellent library.

Answer (score 0):

Just other variant from @Malik's answer.

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\code\cs\sample.txt")
                    .Split(new char[] { ',','\r','\n' });

int[] ints = data.Where(x => x.Count() != 0)
                 .Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
foreach(var e in ints)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```